# Install Emacs without root privilege under my personal directory, error while running ./configure --prefix -my-personal-directory

Tags: unix, emacs, installation, x11

I am using system RedHat 6.8 and I tried to install emacs under my personal directory as I don't have permission to run root command. 
Below is my command:

```
cd emacs-24.5
./configure --prefix -my-home-directory
```

Then I got error message as below:

```
configure: error: The following required libraries were not found:
libXpm libgif/libungif libtiff
Maybe some development libraries/packages are missing?
If you don't want to link with them give
--with-xpm=no --with-gif=no --with-tiff=no
as options to configure
```

I did some google search and it told me I need to install dependence libXpm, libgif/libungif and libtiff, but all instructions online were teaching you how to install these dependence with root privilege, which I don't have.

Then I downloaded source code of libXpm from https://xorg.freedesktop.org/archive/individual/lib/ and run following command

```
tar xvf libXpm-3.5.12.tar.gz
cd libXpm-3.5.12
configure --prefix -my-home-directory
make
make install
```

Then the libXpm successfully installed and I also appended the path to the libXpm in $LD_LIBRARY_PATH by

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/path/to/libXpm:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

However, after that I tried to ./configure emacs again it still output that error

```
configure: error: The following required libraries were not found:
libXpm libgif/libungif libtiff
Maybe some development libraries/packages are missing?
If you don't want to link with them give
--with-xpm=no --with-gif=no --with-tiff=no
as options to configure
```

Anybody can help me out?

Comment: LD_LIBRARY_PATH has no effect on compilation and linking. Try --with-xpm=/path/to/your/installation/of/xpm etc. (Leave LD_LIBRARY_PATH changes on).

Comment: I tried this method but it does not work. I set the --with-xpm = /path/to/my/xpm direcotry/ but still got the same error information when configure emacs.

Comment: Look in the configure logs and see what exactly is being checked when `configure` tries to detect libxpm.

Comment: By checking the log I noticed: 
checking X11/xpm.h usability... no
checking X11/xpm.h presence... no
Then I looked at the code of configure file, looks like --with-xpm cannot change the path to xpm, it can only choose "no" or nothing.

Comment: You are right, unfortunately this configure doesn't support this. You have to add parameters like this: `CPPFLAGS="-I/path/to/xpm/includes -I/path/to/..." LDFLAGS="-L/path/to/xpm/libs -L/path/to/..."`

Comment: Excellent, I appended the local xpm path to CPPFLAGS and LDFLAGS by changing configure file and it works!!
Very appreciate your help!!

Comment: You might want to ask the administrator(s) of the machine whether they would be willing to install some packages for you, which would make things much simpler. E.g. for libXpm, packages libXpm and libXpm-devel need to be installed. Of course, if you are doing this in order to learn, keep going as you are!